# Displaying monthly data in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a series of data with a single datapoint every month using the OHLC renderer. I am trying to display it with jqplot. It looks fine, except the data points are far too skinny because jqplot is displaying them as if they only apply to that day. When I take out the date, and just specify month and year, jqplot crashes.

My data looks like this:

```
    [
        [
            "01/01/2008", 
            8152.9054008104704, 
            2612.7075024153296, 
            5382.8064516128998
        ], 
        // ...
        [
            "03/01/2008", 
            7554.0494491662403, 
            2086.69248631764, 
            4820.3709677419401
       ], 
    ]
```

Is this configuration possible, or should I hack the code myself? The [documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html) doesn't make it clear how to do this.

What code should I be modifying? `DateAxisRenderer`? `OHLCRenderer`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use tickInterval option with jqplot.DateAxisRenderer plugin to create monthly ticks.

```
xaxis: {
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
              formatString:'%#d %I:%M %p'
        },
        rendererOptions: {
              daTickInterval: [1, 'month']
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jagadish's `rendererOptions` did not work for me.  However, this did:

```
axes:{
    xaxis:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
      tickOptions:{formatString:'%b/%e/%Y'},
      tickInterval:'1 month'
    }
  },
```